# How to avoid inspect element in HTML page?

Tags: php, html, security

Suppose I have a select tag on the HTML page .
User can right click on the select tag and click Inspect element then user can change value of option tag and then send data .
Whether there is a way to avoid this problem?

Comment: Someone can still make there own form and submit it to your site, sanitize your input.

Comment: I think that if you are tagging this as a security concern you are addressing the wrong issue. The HTML you send to the browser is just a way to help the user to interact with your logic. You server side scripts should always validate and sanitize input no matter if the user can see your HTML or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to prevent it like that it is useless at best and a terrible user experience at worst.

What you should do is validate the data on the serverside. This can be done easily by keeping a list of valid values on the server side.

Simple example:

```
<?php

$validValues= [
    'val1',
    'val2',
    'val3',
];

if (!in_array($_POST['yourfield'], $validValues, true)) {
    // error
}
```

Comment: it is the effective way, but it's not always an efficient way. I am used to working on the DOM, client side validation, and less of server side validation. Because of the DOM is user-customizable, i do some tricks to keep the data sent are  valid. Of course it is not a good behavior. but, making server side validation is doubling the effort. -_-

Answer (score 2):

That is actually one of the reasons, why you should always validate your data at backend.
Even if you disable right click the user would be able to change the form data.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve disabling right click by using jQuery.

```
$(document).bind('contextmenu', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('Right Click is not allowed');
});
```

But unfortunately that will not solve your problem. There are many developer tools available to code debugging or Inspect element.

It is very difficult to stop everything.

Comment: Disabling right click is just a bad idea unless you have written a highly specific web application.

Comment: Hmm. You might as well disable the CTRL+SHIFT+J key sequence. And the F12 key on the keyboard, too.

Answer (score 0):

One could tell you how to disable right click, but that is not a true solution. If you are worried about using Javascript to input manipulated variables into your code, then just validate and/or sanitize the user input, which should be a sine qua non in any web application. PHP has some great tools nowadays for easily sanitizing input: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php.